# The game goes back to title screen after character creation

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-jedi-knight-jedi-academy

Jedi Knight: Jedi Academy will go through the opening stage of creating a character, but once I have completed this, the game will abruptly take me back to the main menu with the message :

> CL_ParseGamestate: bad command byte

How do I fix this?

Comment: What operating system are you trying to run it on? The version (e.g. Windows 8, Windows 10) and the bits (e.g. 32 bit, 64 bit) are both going to be relevant to this question. I'm not familiar with the specific game, but I can help you improve your question.

Comment: mention any mods you may have installed. FYI JKJA is a quake-3 engine game, so this might help you broaden the search a little.

Comment: If you're running it in later version of Windows try running XP compatibility mode

Comment: My suggestion to anyone finding this error, would be to test on a fresh install with no mods and see what happens. The user above did not mention his setup, which is more than relevant to all Jedi Academy errors. The number one cause of JKA errors is mods.